# Read data from a url behind a proxy

Tags: node.js

**WEB Server I want to connect to**

I have a web service running in a private network. This server is a web service which I can see working in the browser if I set the socks proxy in the browser.

**My Service**

I need   **node.js server** on my machine to use the socks proxy to connect and call the web server

**My UseCase**

I need to do post requests for xml data as well as do some get requests.

**My Problem**

My app is not able to connect to the server hidden behind the socks proxy.
I do not want to set the global proxy for node or anything, only for one part of the app.

**Updated : Working Solution**

While the answer directs in the correct direction, I will include the final working solution here for reference as it needed a few modifications to the examples on github

```
    var shttp = require('socks5-http-client');
    var options = {} ; 
    options.host = 'ip.of.web.service';
    options.port = 1919;     //port of webservice
    options.path = '/control/getjson';    //path on webservice to get
    options.socksPort = 8778;       //socks proxy port
    options.socksHost = 'ip.of.socks.proxy';  

    var req = shttp.get(options, function (res) {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('readable', function () { 
            callback(res);   //send response to my function for further processing.
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using socks proxy is not natively supported in the built in http client object.

Following 2 libraries makes it easy to connect to http endpoints through a socks proxy. Give it a try

Use [socks5-http-client](https://github.com/mattcg/socks5-http-client) for connecting to http endpoints
Use [socks5-https-client](https://github.com/mattcg/socks5-https-client) for connecting to https endpoints